# Terraform: Using Variable to add multiple file names to a string

Tags: terraform

I am trying to pass multiple file names into my terraform script when running `terraform apply`, but I keep facing the same error. Please read on to better understand it. I have added only the relevant code:

I have a folder in my Terraform project called `keys`. Inside the folder I have the following files:

```
samantha.cer
john.cer
```

In `keys.tfvars`:

```
path_to_keys =  "./keys/*.cer"
```

In `variables.tf`:

```
variable "path_to_keys" {
  type        = string
}

variable "key_names" {
  type    = string
  default = "./keys/"
}
```

In `main.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "gw" {
  name                = "team-${terraform.workspace}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"
  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = false
  sku           = "VpnGw1"
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "config"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.ip.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  }

  vpn_client_configuration {
        vpn_client_protocols = ["IkeV2","SSTP"]
        address_space = [var.vpn_client_address_space]
            root_certificate {
            name = "${var.key_names}Root-Cert"
            public_cert_data = var.path_to_keys
          }
        }
```

What I'm trying to do here is place in each key file name before `Root-Cert` to make it easier to spot who has access as I will be adding in more key files in the future.

But the error I receive when I do `terraform apply` is:

```
Error: Creating/Updating Virtual Network Gateway: (Name "team-gwt" / Resource Group "team-gwt-infra-rg"): network.VirtualNetworkGatewaysClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="VpnClientRootCertificateDataInvalid" Message="Data for certificate /subscriptions/subscription-details-retracted-for-security/resourceGroups/team-gwt-infra-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/team-gwt/vpnClientRootCertificates/Root-Cert is invalid." Details=[]
```

What is a future-proof solution to solve this?

Comment: What exactly are the values of `key_names`?

Comment: @Marcin I haven't given them any values in the ```.tfvars``` file as I was previously told to call them using the ```default``` command. I'm still very new to Terraform, so this is a learning process for me.

Comment: Its not even possible to get your error with your current code. Please make sure that the code you post in the question is your real code that produces the error. Otherwise its difficult to help.

Comment: Ok, this is quite weird then as this is the exact code that I have on all of the files. I've double checked it. Apologies.

Comment: This is not possible! Your `key_names` is `list(string)` and default value is a `string`. This will error out immediately and you will not be able to even run your code.

Comment: @Marcin Please accept my sincerest apologies. Looks like you were right. Also, I was doing a ```terraform apply``` rather than ```plan```. The error has been updated as has the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your default value of `"./keys/"` is incorrect. This is wrong name that you are trying to use. The name can only be:

```
Resource name ./keys/Root-Cert is invalid. 
The name can be up to 80 characters long. 
It must begin with a word character, 
and it must end with 
a word character or with '_'. The name may 
contain word characters or '.', '-', '_'."
```

Thus you can try with:

```
variable "key_names" {
  type    = string
  default = "keys"
}
```

Comment: Looks like that has worked, but I unfortunately have a new error now. I've updated the error and it looks as if this may be an issue with the permissions? I'm very grateful for your help

Comment: @abv1998 If you have new error, then a new question should be made.